# Power Bi Data Transform - Returning only currently active records

Tags: database, powerbi, powerquery, data-modeling

I am attempting to transform my data in Power BI to return only the currently active (non-suspended) records, however I am struggling with it.

The tables I am working with follow the below structure:

**Table #1 - Address:**

| PLACEID | ADDRESS |
| --- | --- |
| REF123 | 1 TEST ROAD |
| REF1234 | 2 TEST ROAD |
| REF12345 | 3 TEST ROAD |

**Table #2 - AddressSuspendedHistory:**

| PLACEID | SUSPENDED? | EFFECTIVEDATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| REF1234 | TRUE | 2021-01-01 |
| REF1234 | FALSE | 2023-02-01 |
| REF12345 | TRUE | 2022-05-01 |

I need to return records from the Address table but only ones that aren't **currently** marked as suspended = true in the AddressSuspendedHistory table, but as you can see from the data, sometimes the addresses are unsuspended at a later date.

Here is the data I would wish to return from the above sample data:

Outcome Table:

| PLACEID | ADDRESS |
| --- | --- |
| REF123 | 1 TEST ROAD |
| REF1234 | 2 TEST ROAD |

Thanks in advance for any assistance with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2:

[image]

Group the rows in Table 2 as follows:

```
= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"PLACEID"}, {{"All", each Table.First( Table.Sort( _, {{"EFFECTIVEDATE", Order.Descending}} ))}})
```

Expand as follows:

[image]

In Table 1, do a left outer join.

[image]

Expand:

[image]

Filter:

[image]

[image]

Full code Table 1:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"PLACEID", type text}, {"ADDRESS", type text}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"PLACEID"}, Table2, {"PLACEID"}, "Table2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"SUSPENDED"}, {"SUSPENDED"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Table2", each ([SUSPENDED] <> true))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Full code Table 2

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"PLACEID", type text}, {"SUSPENDED", type logical}, {"EFFECTIVEDATE", type date}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"PLACEID"}, {{"All", each Table.First( Table.Sort( _, {{"EFFECTIVEDATE", Order.Descending}} ))}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"PLACEID"}),
    #"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Removed Columns", "All", {"PLACEID", "SUSPENDED", "EFFECTIVEDATE"}, {"PLACEID", "SUSPENDED", "EFFECTIVEDATE"})
in
    #"Expanded All"
```

Answer (score 2):

I have made a similar solution to @David but I like to avoid grouping when I can in Power Query - instead I use a small trick involving removing duplicates, ordering of the table, and a call to `Table.StopFolding` to isolate the last given status of each distinct `PLACEID` in `Table 2`.

The solution is completed by isolating all `PLACEID`s you want to get rid of in `Table 2` (i.e. where the last status is `true`), and removing these from `Table 1` with a left anti join.

Example snippets for `Table 2` and `Table 1` (in reverse order since you need `Table 2` for `Table 1`):

```
let
  Source = Table.FromRecords({
    [PLACEID="REF1234", SUSPENDED=true, EFFECTIVEDATE="2021-01-01"],
    [PLACEID="REF1234", SUSPENDED=false, EFFECTIVEDATE="2023-02-01"],
    [PLACEID="REF12345", SUSPENDED=true, EFFECTIVEDATE="2022-05-01"]
  }),
  #"Sorted rows" = Table.Sort(Source, {{"EFFECTIVEDATE", Order.Descending}}),
  #"Removed duplicates" = Table.Distinct(Table.StopFolding(#"Sorted rows"), {"PLACEID"}),
  #"Filtered rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed duplicates", each ([SUSPENDED] = true))
in
  #"Filtered rows"
```

```
let
  Source = Table.FromRecords({
    [PLACEID="REF123", ADDRESS="1 Test Road"],
    [PLACEID="REF1234", ADDRESS="2 Test Road"],
    [PLACEID="REF12345", ADDRESS="3 Test Road"]
  }),
  #"Merged queries" = Table.NestedJoin(
    Source, "PLACEID", 
    #"Table 2", "PLACEID", 
    "Data", JoinKind.LeftAnti
  ),
  #"Removed columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Merged queries", {"Data"})
in
  #"Removed columns"
```

Comment: Table.Buffer will force the order to remain for using a Table.Distinct. Table.StopFolding does the same?

Comment: Yes, they would work the same in this query - but I don't want to incur the overhead of actually buffering the table.